# XGBoostClassifier for multiclass and RandomizedSearchCV give nan scores and same probabilities for all classes

Tags: xgboost

X is a df with some categorical and continuous variables, y is a multi-class variable with 5 classes. No variables are in 'object' data type. No `nan` in the df.
Code is as follows.

````py
params = { 'max_depth': np.arange(3,20,1),
       'learning_rate': np.arange(0.01, 0.5, 0.01),
       'subsample': np.arange(0.5, 1.0, 0.1),
       'colsample_bytree': np.arange(0.4, 1.0, 0.1),
       'colsample_bylevel': np.arange(0.4, 1.0, 0.1),
       'gamma': np.arange(0,10,0.05), 
       'reg_alpha': np.arange(0,80,1), 
       'reg_lambda': np.arange(0,1,0.1), 
scoring = {'f1': make_scorer(f1_score, needs_proba=True, multi_class="ovr")} 

#I plan to eventually add more score metrics
xgbc = xgb.XGBClassifier(seed = 20, eval_metric='mlogloss')
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=xgbc, param_distributions=params, scoring=scoring, 
n_iter=10, verbose=False, n_jobs=1, refit = 'f1',return_train_score=False, 
random_state = 30, cv=10)
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.cv_results_)
print(clf.predict_proba(X)) 

#Need estimated probabilities for each class for each row of X 
print("Best parameters:", clf.best_params_) ```
````

The output is:

```
[0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2]
[0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2]
[0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2]
[0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2]]

Best parameters: {'subsample': 0.7, 'reg_lambda': 0.30000000000000004, 'reg_alpha': 58, 'n_estimators': 1000, 'max_depth': 13, 'learning_rate': 0.17, 'gamma': 7.1000000000000005, 'colsample_bytree': 0.4, 'colsample_bylevel': 0.6}

'split8_test_f1': array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]),
 'split9_test_f1': array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]),
 'mean_test_f1': array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]),
```